# How would I hide inno Ready MemoType?

Tags: inno-setup

How can I hide `ReadyMemoType, but not hide or disable the whole ready page? I can't find anything about it in the docs. On the ready to install page, the part that says Setup Type: Custom. That is the part I would like to hide. The text is in Default.isl as "ReadyMemoType", but I don't want to edit what it says. I just want to hide or disable it.

On the inno newsgroup, it was said:

> "In [Code], the event function UpdateReadyMemo is called with the
>   individual text fragments. Simply append these together (with
>   appropriate newlines) in whatever order you wish, omitting whatever
>   you wish, and adding any extra information that you wish."

I have no idea what that means.

Comment: What is `ReadyMemoType` ?

Comment: I also do not know what you mean by `ReadyMemoType`. Maybe `DisableReadyMemo` is what you are looking for? Link to topic in docs - http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_disablereadymemo

Comment: @Dale, if this would be about `ReadyMemo` (how to hide `ReadyMemo`), then the other part of the question *but not hide or disable the whole ready page* would not fit to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the content of the `ReadyMemo` from the [`UpdateReadyMemo`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=UpdateReadyMemo) event method, into which are passed parameters with the information about the stuff to be installed. That includes also the setup type, which is passed as the `MemoTypeInfo` parameter, so to exclude this information from the memo you can concatenate a string without this parameter, for example:

```
[Code]
function UpdateReadyMemo(Space, NewLine, MemoUserInfoInfo, MemoDirInfo, MemoTypeInfo,
  MemoComponentsInfo, MemoGroupInfo, MemoTasksInfo: string): string;
begin
  // the MemoTypeInfo parameter value is not included in this string
  Result :=
    MemoUserInfoInfo + NewLine +
    MemoDirInfo + NewLine +
    MemoComponentsInfo + NewLine +
    MemoGroupInfo + NewLine +
    MemoTasksInfo;
end;
```